# EditorConfig: Enforce spaces after and before opening/closing brackets for C#

Tags: c#, editorconfig

I would like to configure my EditorConfig (https://editorconfig.org/) configuration in a way that the C# code snippet `var v = new Object(kind) {Id = num++};` is automatically reformatted to `var v = new Object(kind) { Id = num++ };` by adding spaces after the opening and before the closing bracket. I went through the documentation and also checked the C# manual (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/editorconfig-code-style-settings-reference?view=vs-2017#example-editorconfig-file) but couldn't quite find a solution yet.

Comment: I'm surprised that there is no way to set preference for object initializer styling in VS 2017/2019.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has implemented there own csharp and dotnet specific options for the .editorconfig.

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/csharp-formatting-options#spacing-options) are the up-to-date spacing options.
I guess you want to do something like that:

```
// csharp_space_before_open_square_brackets = true
int [] numbers = new int [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

// csharp_space_between_empty_square_brackets = true
int[ ] numbers = new int[ ] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

// csharp_space_between_square_brackets = true
int index = numbers[ 0 ];
```

**Disclamer:** For brackets, there are only square properties currently

Comment: What OP was looking for is spacing around braces, not parentheses.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out, unfortunately it seems like only square brackets are currently supported, I replaced the examples.

Comment: This was useful to me; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Resharper (and probably JetBrains Rider), you can use [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/EditorConfig_CSHARP_SpacesPageSchema.html#resharper_csharp_space_within_single_line_array_initializer_braces):

```
resharper_csharp_space_within_single_line_array_initializer_braces = true
```